# Early initializer `new {} with SomeTrait` fails

Tags: scala, traits, anonymous-class

There seems to be a subtlety when using early initializer syntax.

```
trait Base { def callMe = "callMe" }
trait Proxy { this: Base => def call = s"proxied: $callMe" }

val base1 = new Base { }   // non-early init works
val baseFail = new { } with Base   // error: trait Base is abstract; cannot be instantiated
val base2 = new { val n=1 } with Base   // why does this fix the failure?
val proxy = new { } with Base with Proxy   // why doesn't this fail?
```

Why does the `baseFail` line fail, while the other `val`s don't?

The error message is also confusing - I'm not trying to instantiate `Base`, only mix it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `new { } with Base`, there technically *aren't* any early definitions. According to the SLS 5.1.6, the compiler looks for a pattern like this:

```
EarlyDefs         ::= `{' [EarlyDef {semi EarlyDef}] `}' `with'
EarlyDef          ::=  {Annotation} {Modifier} PatVarDef
```

Though it doesn't explicitly say what happens when the sequences of definitions is empty, it seems to just remove them, because when you compile `val a = new { val x = 1 } with Base`, you get something like this after the parsing phase:

```
val a = {
  final class $anon extends Base {
    val x = _;
    def <init>() = {
      val x = 1;
      super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  new $anon()
}
```

But if you empty the braces, you simply get:

```
 val a = new Base()
```

Which is illegal, as is `new Base`.

---

To summarize:

Is an anonymous class, which is allowed
:

```
val base1 = new Base { }
```

Simplifies to `new Base`, which is illegal:

```
val baseFail = new { } with Base
```

Is a proper early definition (not empty) which is allowed:

```
val base2 = new { val n=1 } with Base
```

Simplifies to `new Base with Proxy` which is also allowed:

```
val proxy = new { } with Base with Proxy
```

`new { } with Base { }` also compiles, but it's exactly the same as `new Base { }`, so there's no reason to write it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but the simplest explanation I can think of for this behavior is that the empty early initializer is simply optimized away, so it's equivalent to `val baseFail = new Base` and `val proxy = new Base with Proxy`. `new Base` fails with the same error message, and `new Base with Proxy` is legal because it's an anonymous class. If so, I think it's technically a compiler bug, but quite a minor one.